# Dynamic field access via input

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that looks like below (`this` refers a MongoDB document instance) :

```
  saveResetToken() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.generateResetToken((err: Error, resetToken: string) => {
        if (err) { reject(err) }

        this.resetPasswordToken = resetToken
        this.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000 // 1 hour
        resolve(this.save())
      })
    })
```

`generateResetToken` just returns a generated `resetToken`.

I now have another situation where I am going to be using code that is basically identical except I'll be accessing different fields other than `this.resetPasswordToken` & `this.resetPasswordExpires`.

So ideally I'd like to write & refactor the existing above function to make it reusable.  The initial though is to be able to specify via input the fields that would get set.

Something like:

```
  saveResetToken(tokenField: string, tokenExpires: Date ) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.generateResetToken((err: Error, resetToken: string) => {
        if (err) { reject(err) }

        this.tokenField = resetToken
        this.tokenExpires = Date.now() + 3600000 // 1 hour
        resolve(this.save())
      })
    })
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing looks like I can do the following:

```
  saveExpirableToken(tokenField: string, tokenExpiresField: string, tokenExpiresAt: Date): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.generateResetToken((err: Error, resetToken: string) => {
        if (err) { reject(err) }

        this[tokenField] = resetToken
        this[tokenExpiresField] = tokenExpiresAt
        resolve(this.save())
      })
    })
  },
```